# TrNgGrid display custom column filter

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add custom column filter (autocomplete, select ...) but can't find how. I tried to override default filter template with a `tr-ng-grid-column-filter` attribute on a th, but it does not works. Header is changed somehow (title is not bold anymore) and the new template is not used at all.

Is the `tr-ng-grid-column-filter` right way to do it at all or there is something else?

Data is sorted, paginated and filtered on the server so it does not have any relation to angular or trnggrid client side filtering & formating. So I just want to display some other input on some columns (e.g. select) instead of default input text rendered by a grid.

I'm using angular 1.2.22 with [TrNgGrid](https://github.com/MoonStorm/trNgGrid) 3.0.3

Comment: Can you share your code for better understanding the issue?

Comment: Well, there is really nothing to paste. Just need to display some other input instead of default one.

Answer (score 0):

There are some samples floating around the net. Here's one:

http://plnkr.co/edit/I6JJQD?p=preview

```
<table tr-ng-grid='' items='myItems'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th field-name="name"></th>
            <th field-name="computedTagsField" display-format="computedTags:gridItem">
                <div>
                     <div class="tr-ng-title">Tags</div>
                     <div class="tr-ng-column-filter">
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-options="tag for tag in [null, 'tennis', 'basketball', 'volley']" ng-model="columnOptions.filter"></select>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td field-name="computedTagsField"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a directive to implement a custom drop down filter. It, in itself, can be reused on any project, but it will also give you a good working example of how to implement your own custom filter by simply extending TRNG grid.

**Tutorial:**
http://www.davidcline.info/2015/08/trnggrid-dropdown-column-filter.html

**Demo:**
http://embed.plnkr.co/w39Xt74pippDajyqUIOD/preview