# Custom sorting with custom filtering in TrNgGrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using custom filtering as It was shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29608444/3883369

This is my code

```
<th field-name="FileName" display-name="{{ 'FileName' | translate }}">
    <div class="tr-ng-column-filter tableHeaderOverTitleElement">
        <input class="form-control"
                ng-model="filtersWrapper.mFileName" value=""
                placeholder="{{'refNoAndFilename'|translate}}"
                ng-enter="makeFilteredCallWithDefaultData()">
    </div>
    <div class="tr-ng-title">{{ 'FileName' | translate }}</div>
</th>
```

unfortunatly after adding custom filtering the default sorting disappeared. Could you please help to get sorting back?

[lack of sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp86O.png)

I'm using TrNgGrid version 3.1.7

Answer (score 0):

create user defind search input

```
div class="container" style="padding-left: 0px;">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <div class="input-group" style="    margin-left: 15px;">
        <div class="input-group-addon" style="    padding-left: 15px;"><span> Filter </span></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here..." ng-model="searchFish" style="width: 92%;">
      </div>      
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

short record

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="myTable" style="    width: 99%;max-width: 93%;    text-align: center;" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="border: 0px solid #ddd;" class="textbgcolor textcenter"> user id # <img src="img/up.svg" style="width: 13px;" ng-click="orderProperty = 'user_id'"/> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr  ng-repeat="t in current_table | orderBy:orderProperty | orderBy:use_id | filter:searchFish ">
    <td style="    border: 0px solid #ddd;"> {{t.use_id}} </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

it is funcation direct use

```
//========================================================== asssending and discending oreder funcation

$scope.setOrderProperty = function(propertyName) {
    if ($scope.orderProperty === propertyName) {
        $scope.orderProperty = '-' + propertyName;
    } else if ($scope.orderProperty === '-' + propertyName) {
        $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
    } else {
        $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
    }
}

// -=====================================================

  $scope.sortType     = 'x.user_id' // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term
```